# How to run man with formatting in not interactive shell?

Tags: man, scripting, text-formatting

I have webpage that process ANSI codes and output from man command (underline `A` as `A\x08_`) and I call php shell that execute `bash -c "<command>"` and print the output on the webpage. On the server (it introduce itself as "CloudLinux Server release 6.5 (Pavel Popovich)") `man` command print Ntroff (and they are in bold/underline) but on my local (XUbuntu) the output is not formatted.

Why `man` command differ on these two distros and How can I create function or alias for man that will always print ntroff formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found in `man man` there is environment variable `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` that need to be non empty, but it's not on that server.